# How does the timeline of Logan fit into the X-Men universe?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, logan

According to [this page](http://screenrant.com/logan-movie-xmen-future-year/), *Logan* is just 5 years after the happy ending of *DOFP*. Is this correct?

It doesn't seem to make sense to me. *Logan* seems to be almost post-apocalyptic (well at least for the mutants) and new mutants haven't been born for 25 years. Which seems inconsistent with being just 5 years removed from the happy ending of *DOFP*, where there were plenty of children depicted, as can be seen in this video:

Answer (score 3):

According to director James Mangold, this does indeed take place in the alternate timeline, 5 years after the sunny DOFP ending. I know this is hard to believe, but there is an explanation.

Three things that led to the what we see in Logan:

- Logan started to suffer from Adamantium poisoning, eventually making him incapable as an X-man.
- Professor X killed several X-men in the Westchester incident. This might have defamed the X-men significantly, shutting down the X-mansion. This explains why Charles was kept hidden at the beginning. He is a fugitive.
- Dr. Rice's serum made sure no new mutants are born, for 20 years. So when a tonne of X-men died at Westchester, there were no new mutants to replace them. That was the end.

The result:

- An aging Logan, incapable as a mutant, now works for a living. He's also presumably a fugitive, which is why he is hiding out at the Mexican border.
- An ailing Professor X, with worsening seizures, tormented by the guilt of the Westchester incident.
- No other mutants, but the three.

Comment: I've now also mentioned in my question another big inconsistency, which is that there were plenty of children depicted in the DOFP ending. Which couldn't be the case if no new mutants had been born for 25 years.

Comment: *Explanation 1:* They weren't children. Look closely, and you'll see they're actually late teenagers, at least 19, which makes sense. *Explanation 2:* DOFP was made without "Logan" in mind. And when "Logan" was made, they forgot that detail in DOFP.

Comment: OK, in response to your Explanation 1, I went to look closely and I've now added the clips. Perhaps you should look closely instead.

Comment: You are right then. We shall stick to Explanation 2.

Comment: there is an _implication_ that the Reavers were also hunting down mutants (they tell Caliban that he used to track muties for them), which may explain where all the living mutants went in 5 years. They also may all have just fled to country, as it appears there's safe haven at least in Canada.